# Can another thread access function local by its address \ is this optimization valid \ am I missing something big?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, optimization

Imagine this code:

**Thread1 (func):**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>

struct t_arr
{
    int _[2];
} *volatile pvar = nullptr;

volatile bool var1;

void func(bool x, t_arr ar)
{
    pvar = &ar;

    (x ? ar._[0] : ar._[1]) = 90; //this whole statement optimized out

    while(!var1);
}

typeof(func) *pFunc = func;
```

When I compile it (the exact command is `g++ -O3 -std=gnu++1y  snippet.cpp -pthread`) the resulting body of function `func` is missing the branch where one of `ar` members is assigned the value of 90.

Is this allowed optimization?

What if there is another thread running at the moment waiting for `pvar` to be assigned a value:

**Thread2 (func2):**

```
void func2()
{
    while(!pvar); //wait until 'pvar' is assigned

    printf("%d %d\n", pvar->_[0], pvar->_[1]); //print it members

    var1 = true; //continue 'func'
}
```

Example code creating the above situation:

```
int main () {

    using namespace std;

    thread newthread(func2);

    pFunc(true, {2, 9});

    newthread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

All of the above snippets copied one after another create a single source file (`snippet.cpp`).

If not for each separate piece of code - talk about the whole program which intend is obvious.

Output of the snipper:

```
2 9
```

EDIT: Fixed - forgot to join.

Answer (score 1):

On the optimization. The assignments are made through the variable `ar` which is not marked as `volatile`, the pointer `pvar` is volatile.

Hence those assignment as candidates for removal since the variable is not used again ( as far as the compiler is concerned ).

Making the assignments through the volatile pointer prohibits the compiler from optimizing them out.

```
 (x ? pvar->_[0] : pvar->_[1]) = 90;
```

See the code sample here; the code has not been optimized out, https://goo.gl/lKQcac.

Note; there are further issues with data races that would require suitable synchronization.

Answer (score -1):

The code from function `func` introduces unavoidable race condition - an attempt to modify the variable at the same time when it's read - and since race condition is undefined behavior, compiler is not required to generate the code for undefined behavior.

If the code is to be changed so that race condition is (potentially) elminated, the assignment will be generated. Here is the example code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

struct t_arr
{
    int _[2];
};

std::atomic<t_arr*>  pvar(nullptr);


std::atomic<bool> var1;

void func(bool x, t_arr ar)
{
    pvar = &ar;
    (x ? ar._[0] : ar._[1]) = 90; //this whole statement optimized out

    while(!var1);
}
```

The code above does generate assignments. Also notice that I've replaced inapproriate `volatile` with proper `std::atomic`.

Comment: I'm assigning the local parameter address to a global variable that is allowed to be read during `func` execution.

Comment: @FISOCPP, since the code inadvertenly introduces data race, compiler is not required to generate the code to support undefined behaviour. If you eliminate the race condition, you will see the copy. Let me update the answer with the code.

Comment: Someone could be so nice to explain the reason for downvote?

Comment: @SergeyA: I did not downvote (came here later...). But you code does not eliminate the race condition.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, it provides a theoretical **possibility** (as stated in my answer!) to eliminate race condition through the code unknown to compiler. This is why compiler can not throw the assignment away.